# set explicit size of UITableViewController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, frame

I want to be able to set the size of my tableview depending on what the content is. I would think i could do this in prepareForSegue, since my tableview appears as a popover, if a button is pressed in my rootViewController. So what i'm trying is to set the explicit size, like i can do in storyboard, but i want to do it programmatically. I have tried self.tableview.frame.size, but it get an error, which says it's not assignable?

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"tagView1"])
{
    TagTableViewController *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    tvc.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tvc.tableView.frame.origin.x, tvc.tableView.frame.origin.y , 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TVC's `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    // Change to what you need
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(150.0, 250.0);
}
```

Comment: My problem with this is that It's too late. I create an nsnotification observer in my viewdidload, and it's not till that method has been called, I know which size the popoverview should be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the whole `frame`. And if you want `origin` to stay the same do this:

```
self.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableview.frame.origin.x, self.tableview.frame.origin.y, __width__, __height__);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  to set size of table in vieDidAppear:
 in TVC .

Like:

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - 50)];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Try `self.tableview.frame = (CGRect){self.tableview.frame.origin, newSize};`

Which is the same as `self.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableview.frame.origin.x, self.tableview.frame.origin.y, newSize.width, newSize.height);`, just shorter.

You aren't supposed to directly set the size, because other objects observing the view's frame  won't be notified in that case.

Comment: I tried that - as you can see in the code above, but it's still not working?